# Знаки препинания в тексте

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

«Что же ты мне раньше не сказал,(1) старый шарлатан»,(2) - подумал Сергей и,(3) словно прислушиваясь к тяжести снасти - (4)хотя тяжесть снасти облегчённой на три креветки никак нельзя было почувствовать -(5) или точнее не к тяжести снасти,(6) а к ощущению пустоты вокруг его крючков, (7) по отсутствию интереса к его крючкам, (8) которые тем более нельзя было почувствовать, и всё-таки чувствуя то и другое.

Как объяснить знаки препинания?
1 – Обращение выделяется запятыми.
2 –  Прямая речь выделяется кавычками, и поскольку она стоит перед авторскими словами, то ставится запятая, а потом тире.
3 – Выделяется деепричастный оборот
4 – 5 Выделяется знаками тире вставное предложение.(точно что это вставное предложение?)
6 – Сложносочинённое сопоставительное предложение
7 – ? 
8 – Определительная придаточная часть.
Правильно ли?

Answer (score 2):

Тире там не нужны, только №2 при прямой речи. А вообще знаки препинания должны быть такие:
"Что же ты мне раньше не сказал, старый шарлатан", - подумал Сергей и,
словно прислушиваясь к тяжести снасти, хотя тяжесть снасти, облегченной на
три креветки, никак нельзя было почувствовать, или, точнее, не к тяжести
снасти, а к ощущению пустоты вокруг его крючков, по отсутствию интереса к
его крючкам, которое тем более нельзя было почувствовать, и все-таки
чувствуя и то и другое. 
Проверила по тексту Ф.Искандера.

Comment: Людмила, спасибо!